# How to get the following output using nested for loops in C?

Tags: c, for-loop, nested, scanf

How do you use nested loops in C programming?

Write a program that asks the user to enter a number, and then displays the multiplication table for all numbers from 0 to the number they entered. This should be done with nested for loops. For example, if the user enters 3, they should see:

0 0 0 0
0 1 2 3
0 2 4 6
0 3 6 9

Comment: Don't just paste your assignment here, please show what you tried and explain what doesn't work/where you're stuck.

Comment: It is tempting to say 'you write a second `for` loop as the body of another `for` loop'.  It is a literal answer to your question.  You should really show what you've tried.

Answer (score 4):

Since it is homework, I'm going to describe the way of thinking that leads to solution rather than solution itself. First look at the desired output:

```
0 0 0 0
0 1 2 3
0 2 4 6
0 3 6 9
```

You will realize that this output is equal to:

```
0*0 0*0 0*0 0*0
1*0 1*1 1*2 1*3
2*0 2*1 2*2 2*3
3*0 3*1 3*2 3*3
```

Then you will realize that each number is equal to the **index of line** multiplied by the **index of column** and the newline character is printed at the end of every line. After that you should be able to write it easily on your own :)

Answer (score 2):

pseudo-code

```
for x = 0 to num
  for y = 0 to num
    print x * y
  print newline
```